# Custom Claim with Boolean type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to create an ASP.NET MVC 5 app. I'm using the Identity framework to add claims to a user after authentication. It's easy enough to add claims based on the built-in `ClaimTypes`, but I'm having challenges adding a custom claim that's a Boolean.

I've created this static class to hold my custom claim types:

```
public static class CustomClaimTypes
{
    public static readonly string IsEmployee = "http://example.com/claims/isemployee";
}
```

Then I try to add a custom claim to the `ClaimsIdentity` object:

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.IsEmployee, isEmployee));
```

It gives this error on the line above:

> cannot convert from 'bool?' to 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity'

All the examples that I'm finding are adding strings. How do you add a bool, int, or other type? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The claims can only be represented as strings.  Any numbers, booleans, guids, whatever all have to be strings when added to the claims collection.  So `ToString()` it.

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(
    new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.IsEmployee, 
    isEmployee.GetValueOrDefault(false).ToString()));
```

Comment: Thanks, @Amy. Is it possible to store complex objects in a custom claim? Been reading this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-create-a-custom-claim

Comment: You must serialize them to a string.

Comment: What if i want  "myType": true  instead of "myType":"true" when I decode my payload? 
Because if i use ToString() I will receive the second option.

Comment: @BlackShawarna **Any numbers, booleans, guids, whatever all have to be strings when added to the claims collection.**  It *must* be a string.

Comment: Yes, I agree wih you, There's no other option. 
To have "myToken": false use the ClaimValueTypes.Boolean otherwise you will have "myToken": "false" as string format.

Answer (score 21):

You can also pass **valueType** as third parameter.

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(
    new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.IsEmployee, 
    isEmployee.ToString(), 
    ClaimValueTypes.Boolean));
```

so on front end you will get bool type value instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct type you want in the response, you need to overload ***TokenEndpointResponse***

```
public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
        {
            foreach (var item in context.Identity.Claims)
            {
                object value;

                if (item.ValueType.Contains("boolean"))
                    value = bool.Parse(item.Value);
                else
                    value = item.Value;

                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(item.Type, value);
            }

            return base.TokenEndpointResponse(context);
        }
```

of course after specifying the ***ClaimValueTypes*** as mentioned in previous answers, otherwise it will identify all fields as string type.