# How to add a Claim to a SystemUser as a flag(bool) in C#

Tags: c#, claims

I need to add a `Claim` to be passed to the `front-end`. I want to check `"IsSystemUser"` of type `bool` and then value of the `bool` of course so users are not able to see system settings.

I am using this:

```
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("IsSystemUser", ));
```

However, I noticed that it has string Type, string Value and/or string ValueType.

The `IntentUser` already has a field `isSystemUser`, I just don't know how to add claim to it.

```
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("IsSystemUser", user.IsSystemUser.ToString()));
```

Is that how I should do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Claim with Boolean type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677784/custom-claim-with-boolean-type)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Claims always have a string value ([you can read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677784/custom-claim-with-boolean-type/44677996#44677996)). There is a possibility to specify `valueType` as Boolean:

```cs
context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("IsSystemUser", user.IsSystemUser.ToString(),
                          ClaimValueTypes.Boolean));
```

However, on the front-end, you have to parse it manually from string.